# Crie um objeto que contenha quatro palavras. Use a função sample para fazer uma amostra de 1000 valores desse objeto

Tags: r, funções

...continuando-Descubra como usar a função table para saber quantas vezes cada palavra foi sorteada.

Criei as 4palavras que sao "oi" "ola" "hey" e "hi"
mas quando tentei de acordo com um exmplo que vi no youtube deu errado porque nao sao vectores.

criacao:
`pal<-c("oi","ola","hey","hi")
sample(pal,1000,replace=TRUE)`

execucao:

`head(pal)
levels(pal)`

foi dai que deu erro porque no exemplo que vi o cara estava trabalhando com vectores

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poste o código ao invés de uma imagem. Ajuda a testar :)

Answer (score 3):

Olhe:

```
 pal <- c("oi","ola","hey","hi")
 > is.factor(c("oi","ola","hey","hi"))
 [1] FALSE
 > is.vector(c("oi","ola","hey","hi"))
 [1] TRUE
```

Assim `pal` é um vetor e não um vetor de categoria, por isso `levels()` não funciona.

simplesmente de o ctrl+r na linha `sample(pal,1000, replace=TRUE)` do seu scripts e veja oque ocorre.
 Força aí, todos nós já fomos n00bs.

Answer (score 2):

Tem certeza que você copiou o código certo? Não é algo do tipo:

```
pal <- c("oi","ola","hey","hi")
palavreado <- sample(pal,1000, replace=TRUE)
table(palavreado)
palavreado
hey  hi  oi ola 
251 245 240 264
```

Comment: Obrigado havia esquecido e de alocar a amostra a uma variavel. erro de novato :))

Comment: @bonyduque E já agora, quando usar funções que escolhem aleatoriamente ou geram números aleatórios, como `sample`, comece por chamar `set.seed(numero inteiro)`. Assim os resultados serão reprodutíveis.